# Expand constexpr array into positional function arguments

Tags: c++, metaprogramming, c++20, template-meta-programming

I'm used to using x macros to have powerful code generation. One of the features I like specifically is that I can't mess up the order of the values nor can I forget one.

I want to know if there's a similar strategy for arrays and function params

For example:

If a library provides a function:

```
void foobar(std::string_view k, std::string_view l, std::string_view m);
```

and in my code base I have:

```
constexpr std::array<std::string_view, 3> kConstants{"one", "two", "three"};
```

Is there some expansion magic I can do to get something like:

```
foobar(kConstants);
```

Note for this to be useful to me I must do this without modifying `foobar`. I know I can do something like this with x macros.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You're looking for [`std::apply`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/utility/apply):

```cpp
std::apply(foobar, kConstants);
```

Answer (score 1):

> Is there some expansion magic I can do to get something like: `foobar(kConstants)`? Note for this to be useful to me I **must do this without modifying** `foobar`. I know I can do something like this with x **macros**.

Yes this is possible with template metaprogramming as shown below. Also note that there is no need to use **macros** when there is an option to do using templates.

In the following program, I've created a function template that collects array elements and then passes the at the end of recursion to `foobar`. Note that I've named that function `helperOfFoobar` but you can also name this the same as `foobar` and that will also work as C++ supports overloading of function and function templates. [Demo](https://godbolt.org/z/zrza65vG9)

```
//to end recursion
template<std::size_t N, typename... Elements> void helperOfFoobar(const std::array<std::string_view, N>& arr, Elements... elements)
requires (sizeof...(elements) == N)
{
      foobar(elements...); //since this is the end of recursion, we call foobar by passing all the collected elements
      
      //just for debugging I am print the elements
      ((std::cout << elements << ' '), ...);         //PRINTS: one two three AS EXPECTED
}
//recursively call this and pass elements as arguments
template<std::size_t N, typename... Elements> void helperOfFoobar(const std::array<std::string_view, N>& arr, Elements... elements)
requires (sizeof...(elements) != N)
{
    helperOfFoobar(arr, elements..., arr[sizeof...(elements)]); //collect array elements and pass them recusively
}

constexpr std::array<std::string_view, 3> kConstants{"one", "two", "three"};
int main()
{
   helperOfFoobar(kConstants);   
}
```

[Working demo](https://godbolt.org/z/Evd9jzaf1)

---

Note also that there has been no modification of/in `foobar` since that is your requirement.

---

Finally, this can easily(trivially) be converted to work with C++17 by changing the `requires` clause to `enable_if`.

Comment: Any reason not to simply use `std::apply` as shown in Barry's answer ?

Comment: @wohlstad It's never bad/wrong to read/create more solutions to/for a given problem. I have just shown what I would use if I were to write my own solution without using standard's predefined function template etc. My point is that the more solutions one read about, the more they can learn(or at least they have the option to learn). I am not saying which of the solutions is better but just that I use this solution very often in my own programs and so wanted to show that there is also one other way of solving the given problem.

Comment: Well, that not wrong of course in general. But where there is such an elegant solution in the standard library I personally see no reason to reinvent the wheel.

Comment: @wohlstad I agree that there is already a simple solution in the standard library, but that doesn't mean people should stop trying to find more solutions to a given problem. Any solution can be useful to some future reader(s) so I've the option to write it as an answer here on Stackoverflow. The question was not to find the "best" solution but to find "a" solution.

Comment: Very ingenious solution!